# Setting UITextView exclusion paths within UITableViewCell fails to layout properly

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am trying to specify a word wrap around an image within a `UITableViewCell`. I have a `UITextView` and a `UIImageView` (on top). When there is an image present for a given cell, the image will be unhidden and the exclusion paths will be set on the `textContainer` within the `UITextView`. When there is no image, the `textContainer.exclusionPaths` is set to `nil`. The problem is that when there is no image, the exclusion path remains set and sometimes vice versa (the exclusion paths are set, but the text doesn't wrap). I am using `dequeueCellWithIdentifier` within the `UITableView` and calling my function `setFields` (within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`). When the cell gets reinitialized, the exclusion path works most of the time. I'm thinking it has to do with timing. Any help is appreciated.

```html
 func setFields(avatar:UIImage?, author:String?, text:String?, images:[AnyObject], timestamp:String?){

  
  ....

  self.thumbImageView.image = nil
  self.thumbImageView.imageURL = nil
  self.thumbImageView.hidden = true
  self.titleText.textContainer.exclusionPaths = nil
  
  if images.count > 0 {
   self.images = images
   if images is [UIImage] {
    self.thumbImageView.image = images[0] as? UIImage
   } else  {
    self.thumbImageView.imageURL = NSURL(string: images[0] as String)
   }
   
   self.cycleToImage(0)
   
   self.thumbImageView.hidden = false
   
   let convertedFrame:CGRect = self.titleText.convertRect(self.thumbImageView.frame, fromView: self)
   let exclusionPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: convertedFrame, cornerRadius: 0.0);
   self.titleText.textContainer.exclusionPaths = [exclusionPath]
  }
  
 }
```